# Can't sftp to remote server via SSH using RSE in eclipse while on VPN(Cisco AnyConnect)

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, ssh, vpn

Everything is fine while I'm using Windows XP but after upgrading to windows 7, I can no longer access remote systems (vms and linux servers) using RSE in eclipse while on VPN(Cisco AnyConnect). I'm getting pop-up message RSEG1066 -- Failed to connect sshd on :22. detail button says "java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect"

I can access those systems via SSH in putty from the same Windows environment. Any eclipse users here experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the module used by RSE to connect to the remote server is not yet compatible with java 7. Reverting back to older version (java 6 in my case) solves the issue.